# Root test to determine constant for which series is convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Determine the upper limit on the constant $k$ for which the following series is
>   convergent
>
> $$\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{3^{kr}(r!)^2}{(3r)!r^{-r}}.$$
>
> [You may use $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty}(1+1/x)^x=e]$

I tried to apply the ratio test, which gave

$$\lim_{r \to \infty}\left|\frac{3^k(r+1)^{r+3}r^r}{(3r+3)(3r+2)(3r+1)}\right|<1.$$

But I'm not sure how to proceed from there, or how the given limit is useful.

Comment: You couldn't possible get that limit you wrote as (1) it isn't true, and (2) that'd give you that the series converges and thus there is no question at all...

Comment: Anyone who can do mathematics can see that that is the inequality that you would impose to ensure for a sufficient condition of convergence using the quotient rule. Now you can compute the limit. Note that $3^k$ is constant, $\frac{r+1}{3r+3}\to\frac{1}{3}$, $\frac{r+1}{3r+2}\to\frac{1}{3}$, $\frac{r+1}{3r+1}\to\frac{1}{3}$ as $r\to\infty$. However, those factors are multiplied by $(r+1)^{r+1}r^r$ which tends to $\infty$ as $r\to\infty$. Therefore, the limit is $\infty$ for all values of $k$. Possibly there is a typo in the problem.

Comment: The upper limit is $-\infty$, since lub of empty set i, by def.  or there is a  typo in your question

Comment: I don't think your ratio is correct. Shouldn't $r^r$ be $(1+\frac{1}{r})^r$?

Comment: The factor $r^r$ in the numerator should be $r^{-r}$. With the correction the limit is $\frac{3^ke}{27}$.

Comment: Thanks @RRL, that was my problem!

Answer (score 1):

The main result needed
for expressions involving factorials
is that
$\dfrac{(x!)^{1/x}}{x} \to \dfrac1{e}
$
as $x \to \infty$.

This allows us to
use the root test
on expressions like these.

In your case,

$\begin{array}\\
\left(\dfrac{3^{kr}(r!)^2}{(3r)!r^{-r}}\right)^{1/r}
&=\dfrac{3^k}{r^{-1}}\left(\dfrac{(r!)^{2/r}}{((3r)!)^{1/r}}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{3^k}{r^{-1}}\dfrac{((r!)^{1/r})^2}{(((3r)!)^{1/(3r)})^3}\\
&\to r3^k\dfrac{(r/e)^2}{(3r/e)^3}\\
&= r3^k\dfrac{e}{9r}\\
&= \dfrac{3^ke}{9}\\
\end{array}
$

For the sum to converge,
the root says that
we want
$\dfrac{3^ke}{9} < 1
$
or
$3^k < 9/e$
or
$3^{k-2} < 1/e$
or
$(k-2)\ln 3 < -1$
or
$k < 2-\dfrac1{\ln 3}
$.